# Access Photo Library via Objective-C/Xcode in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, photo

I'm writing an iPhone application.  I'm wondering if I can get a list of files/filenames of the photos stored in the iPhone library (or those in the simulator).

Essentially, I'm asking if I can get the filenames of the photos stored on the iPhone or simulator.

I appreciate any help, thanks!

EDIT:

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"/Users/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0002.jpg"];
imageView.image = image;
```

doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9):

You simply have to use the `UIImagePickerController`.

It gives something like that:

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    // Don't forget to add UIImagePickerControllerDelegate in your .h
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    } else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Sorry -- I'm interested in the filename/path!  Thanks!

Comment: I think you can't have access to the filename/path of an image stored in the iOS filesystem.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Don't forget when you add the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate you also need the UINavigationControllerDelegate

Answer (score 3):

This is something of a duplicate of a SO question asked already here - [Get list of all photo albums and thumbnails for each album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705478/get-list-of-all-photo-albums-and-thumbnails-for-each-album-ios)

From that answer:
Take a look at [AssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730) framework.

Note that if you have access to the iOS 6 Beta, you'll want to note the changes taking place for accessing those assets. Can say no more per NDA.

Comment: Sorry -- how can I do it without using that framework?  I just need a filename/path.  Thanks!

Comment: Just seeing this - you don't have access to the filename/path unless on a jailbroken device. This is per the sandboxing security of all apps.

Answer (score -3):

Using this methods, you can easily implement that.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/trmg44a93hwq35x/AACAVGY6VKEDR0tDUOqoxd-Ba?dl=0