# Set image to the image view from Gallery without select the image from the Image Gallery

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to IOS app development. I have one problem. I have to get an image from the Image Gallery of the iPhone without letting the user select the image. I need to programatically set the image name of the image I need to get the Image. Any one please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch images from Gallery programmatically using `AssetLibrary`.

These can be helpful [Tutorial1](https://codemastergabriel.wordpress.com/2013/11/22/access-mediaphotosvideos-using-alassetslibrary-iosobjective-c/) and [Tutorial2](http://five.agency/accessing-photo-library-using-assets-library-framework-on-iphone/)

This stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633843/get-all-of-the-pictures-from-an-iphone-photolibrary-in-an-array-using-assetslibr) could also be helpful

Once the images are fetch you can select and then set it to any `UIImageView`

Comment: finally am getting images but image names am not able getting image names  image <UIImage: 0x9f14230> how to get the image names

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you'd like to do is not allowed on iOS.

You have to use UIImagePickerController, ask permission from the user, and let the user choose an image.

Check this thread: [Access Photo Library via Objective-C/Xcode in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319463/access-photo-library-via-objective-c-xcode-in-ios)