# How to add image in PHAsset and delete it from photo library?

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, photo, photokit, phasset

I am working on an app like hiding photos and I want to move the images to my app so for that I have to import images from photo library and delete that image from library but I cant understand how to work with `PHAssets` and where to implement.

I used the UIPickerview to pick the image and then delete it from library please anyone can help me for that

**This the picker where I get image :**

```
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
```

**And this is for delete but what is asset :**

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:formatWithOrientation];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Finished deleting asset. %@", (success ? @"Success." : error));
}];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. It's working for me.

```
PHFetchResult *asset = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@“Your asset url” options:nil];

 [asset enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
 NSLog(@"%@",[obj class]);
 [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
     BOOL req = [obj canPerformEditOperation:PHAssetEditOperationDelete];
     if (req) {
         NSLog(@"true");
         [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:@[obj]];
     }
 } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Finished Delete asset. %@", (success ? @"Success." : error));
     if (success) {
        NSLog(@“delete successfully”);  
    }
}];
}];
```

Comment: but how to get image url

Comment: For that you have to import image using ALAssetsLibrary instead of UIImagePicker

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705478/get-list-of-all-photo-albums-and-thumbnails-for-each-album

Comment: this work and doesnt work to use AlAssets you can directly get url from uiimagepicker using NSURL *imageurl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];    then add it to nsmutablearray and problem solve

Comment: ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated so u can't get asset url. so I think u can delete by image local identifier.

Comment: @kb920 it will delete image one by one, how can we delete multiple image at once.