# How to search an Image file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsinputstream

Is there anyway to check whether a particular image file exists in my iPhone. Lets say my image name is IMG_123.JPG. I want to search this image and if it exists I want to create a `NSInputStream` object using that File. If the image is not in `NSBundle` it can be saved in photo library or somewhere.

Please help me.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* dataPath = [documentsDirectory  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IMG_2594.JPG"];
```

**UPDATE  2**

Getting the image when user click the picker image

```
copyOfOriginalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[imageAsset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]];
```

Convert the image into NSData

```
imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(copyOfOriginalImage, 1.0);
```

Then I convert it into base64

```
strEncoded=[imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Comment: Is the image file is in the document directory in sand box???

Comment: no I just saved it in my photo library

Comment: lets say its a image taken by phone camera. And I can get the name of it using image picker

Answer (score 1):

Your image can be at `documentdirectory` or `assets` or `appbundle` in your application.

Images which are located in `photolibrary`, you can't called it part of your app's database.

So, you can check that your image is available in `documentdirectory` or any directory like `tempdirectory` or `customdirectory` if you have made like,

```
 NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *filesIndir = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];

if ([filesIndir containsObject:@"IMG_123.JPG"]) {

    NSLog(@"document directory contains : IMG_123.JPG");
}
```

It will check directly in document directory. If you are making custom directory in document directory then provide path of it.

Now If your image is in app bundle then you can check it like,

```
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_123.JPG"];

if (image) {

    NSLog(@"yes image available in app bundle");
}
```

If your image is in `assests` then you can check it like,

```
   UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_123"];

if (image2) {

    NSLog(@"yes image available in assets");
}
```

Now, for checking image is available in photo library, This is a bit critical task that you should have the list of all images and then you can check that it available or not. For that you have to use [ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/).

Refer [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633843/get-all-of-the-pictures-from-an-iphone-photolibrary-in-an-array-using-assetslibr) for managing this.

You can refer [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705478/get-list-of-all-photo-albums-and-thumbnails-for-each-album) also.

Comment: What I have done sofar is first I take the image name from the asset library. Then I want to search the real path of it. see my updated question.. Now I want to read this actual file using NSInputStream.

Comment: IS it correct the way I have done,, and can I read the actual file using this path using NSInputStream?

Comment: what you want to achieve ? tell me requirement

Comment: I want to upload user selected image to my server. Server needs a byte array of my UIImage.I encoded to base64 and send to the server. But my data doesnt accept by the server. If I encoded it with an online tool and send then it qccept,, also I checked the same image for both iOS and Android but base64 string is different. But Android one is accept by the server. So I checked how android one get the byte array from the image. It has used INputstream to get the byte data.like this public static byte[] readBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

Comment: So I need to do the same thing in iOS too

Comment: have you tried something like, `NSString *byteArray = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];` ?  If image is jpeg then jpegrepresentation!!

Comment: have you tried normal way to send image to server as normal data (i.e. in multipart form data)  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122261/discussion-between-irrd-and-ketan-parmar).